# Use only one font for a website for all operating systems - Which files are required?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, fonts

is there a way to use one font **for all operating systems** (*Windows, Linux, iOS, Android, ...*) **on a website**? **Which file types** do I need **for which operating system?** I have been told that .ttf files are for iOS systems and .woff / .woff2 files cover almost all operating systems. But which systems does .woff not cover for example? Which file types do I need to use one font for all systems for my website?

TIA

Comment: websites cannot impose fonts on clients

Comment: Woff is supported by every platform.